# ¿Cómo hago print del nombre de la variable de la clase?

Tags: python

Quiero imprimir el nombre de la variable de la clase, he provado esto:

```
class nombreDeClase:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)
nombreDeVariable = nombreDeClase()
```

esto al ser ejecutado, imprimiría lo siguiente:

```
nombreDeClase
```

Pero quiero que imprima lo siguiente:

```
nombreDeVariable
```

¿Se puede hacer? En tal caso, ¿como se haría?

Comment: No existe la información que pides. Un objeto no guarda la lista de variables que le referencian. No se necesita un nombre de variable para crear un objeto. Crear un objeto y asignarlo a una variable son dos operaciones independientes. Un objeto puede ser creado y usado sin nunca tener un nombre (como parte de una expresión, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 4):

Lo que menciona Candid Moe es totalmente cierto, los objetos no tienen la referencia  a los nombres de variables (es al revés), y el otro problema es que en el `__init()__`, el objeto aún no ha sido referenciado.

Sin embargo, hay algo a medio camino de lo que pides, que es buscar en el espacio de nombres global, aquellas variables que referencien al objeto, claro que no puedes hacerlo en `__init()__` como ya mencioné y  tienes que tener en cuenta, que puede que exista más de una variable que referencie a un mismo objeto, por lo que retornar una cadena no es lo más apropiado:

La idea es más o menos así:

```
class nombreDeClase:
  def print_varnane(self):
    d = globals()
    print([k for k in d if d[k] is self])

nombreDeVariable = nombreDeClase()
otraReferencia = nombreDeClase()
otraReferenciaMas = otraReferencia

nombreDeVariable.print_varnane()
otraReferencia.print_varnane()

['nombreDeVariable']
['otraReferencia', 'otraReferenciaMas']
```

Comment: El operador igualdad `==` se usa para comparar valores. Para saber si dos objetos son el mismo se debe usar el operador `is`.... `[k for k in d if d[k] is self]`. Obviamente, el problema de usar `globals()` es que todas referencias locales quedan fuera de su alcance.

Answer (score 2):

Intentando seguir con la idea de usar `inspect`, creo que se puede hacer más directo desde el mismo método `__init__`:

```py
import inspect
import re

pat = re.compile("\s*([A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*=")


class NombreVariable:

    def __init__(self):
        self.varname = "<Sin nombre>"

        previus_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        try:
            self.inspect_caller(previus_frame)
        finally:
            del previus_frame

    def inspect_caller(self, previus_frame):
        source = inspect.getframeinfo(previus_frame).code_context[0]
        m = pat.match(source)
        if m:
            self.varname = m.group(1)
        

nombreVariable = NombreVariable()          
print("Nombre Variable:", nombreVariable.varname)
```

### Funcionamiento

Básicamente, se intentará analizar el código fuente desde donde se invoca la creación de la instancia y su asignación a una variable:

```py
nombreVariable = NombreVariable()  # <-- buscamos esta línea de código
```

En el `__init__` empezamos por obtener una referencia al *frame* desde donde se solicita crear la instancia usando `inspect.currentframe().f_back`. De este *frame* extraemos las líneas de código de contexto mediante `inspect.getframeinfo`. Si no indicamos otra cosa, por defecto sólo nos devuelve una línea de código, suficiente en la mayoría de los casos para obtener el nombre de la variable a la que se asigna la instancia.

Con el patrón `"\s*([A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*="` se busca una asignación del tipo `variable = ...`. Si se encuentra, se extrae el nombre de la variable y se usa en el atributo `varname`.

Puede que haya código para el que se necesite más de una línea de contexto para conseguir hallar el nombre de la variable. Por poner un ejemplo raro:

```py
nombreVariable\
=\
NombreVariable()
```

No es posible abarcar todas las casuísticas, por lo que se confía que siempre se harán las asignaciones en la misma línea (como es habitual).

[Está recomendado borrar el *frame* una vez finalizada su utilidad](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) con el fin de evitar referencias cruzadas entre objetos que dificulten la labor del *recolector de basura* (gc). Es por ello que se blinda su uso en un `try..finally` con el fin de garantizar su borrado al final.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @Candid no hay una forma inmediata de hacerlo. Sin embargo, he encontrado lo siguiente: [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python).

Como respuesta corta indican que no la hay, como respuesta larga que sí pero que son soluciones largas y nada aceptables en entornos de producción.

Aún así, adaptaré el código a tu clase:

```
import inspect, re

class nombreDeClase:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

    def nombreVariable(self, p):
        for linea in inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe().f_back)[3]:
            m = re.search(r'\bnombreVariable\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\s*\)', linea)
            if m:
                print(m.group(1))

instanciaClase = nombreDeClase()
instanciaClase.nombreVariable(instanciaClase)
```

**Dónde el resultado sería**:

```
$ -> python3 variable_name.py 
instanciaClase
```

Pero como el propio autor indica, es una "horrible solución basada en inspecciones".

Answer (score 0):

Una forma adicional corta (aunque limitada, porque *siempre va a imprimir el nombre con el valor de la variable*) sería con f-string debugging (esto funciona para Python 3.8 en adelante).

```
a = "variable123"
print(f"{a=}")
```

El output sería:

```
a='variable123'
```